# SPARQL VALUES BLOCK AND GRAPH

Tags: sparql

I am trying to replace the value of code_type when it is empty and belongs to ifcowl:IfcSite with "INF" via this attempt. I don't know if this is possible.

First, I get the code_type values I need and I use the "values" block to replace the values

However, some values are empty and among these empty values, I have to replace the empty value by "INF" but only for ifcowl = IfcSite

Here is my attempt and thank you in advance for your help :

```
select ?code_type ?gid ?VALUE1 ?TEST

PREFIX ifcowl: <http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifcOWL/IFC2X3_TC1#>
PREFIX express: <https://w3id.org/express#>
PREFIX blabla: <https://www.blabla.fr/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
PREFIX iso23386: <https://www.iso.org/standard/iso23386#>
{

     ?o a ?class .
     GRAPH blabla:optimized {
        OPTIONAL {?o blabla:SEQ_GUID  ?gid}
        OPTIONAL {?o blabla:code_type ?code_type}
        OPTIONAL {?o blabla:VALUE1 ?VALUE1}
       
       
       FILTER (?code_type IN
      (""^^xsd:string, "ATE_PCO"^^xsd:string, "ATE_SCA"^^xsd:string, "ATE_TNT"^^xsd:string))

}
   optional {
                values (?code_type ?TEST) {
                        ("" "ZONE" && ?class = ifcowl:IfcSite)

                       
                }
   }


   optional {
                values (?code_type ?TYPE) {
                        ("ATE_PCO" "PCO")
                        ("ATE_SCA" "CABLE")
                        ("ATE_TNT" "TNT")
                       
                }
                values (?code_type ?NOMOS) {
                        ("ATE_PCO" "ABC")
                        ("ATE_SCA" "BDC")
                        ("ATE_TNT" "EDG")

                      
                }
        }

   
}
```

Comment: I don't get what your query is doing, also your query doesn't even try to `replace` anything. Also what is `("" "ZONE" && ?class = ifcowl:IfcSite)` ? that is not legal SPARQL syntax, would be good if you at least try to follow the syntax published at the W3C specs

Comment: if you want something applied only for a single case, use a separate `OPTIONAL` and either a triple pattern the matches `ifcowl = IfcSite` or a `FILTER EXISTS`

Comment: Hello @UninformedUser, thank you.
Is it possible to recover values on 2 graphs:
A first graph blabla:optimized and a second graph ifcowl

Among the data of these 2 graphs: 
I want to retrieve the code_type with value "ATE_PCO" "ATE_SCA" "ATE_TNT" and "" and replace the empty values of code_type = "" only if ifcowl=ifcsite by "INF"

Comment: if you want to handle separate graphs you can use a `UNION` operator in SPARQL. And if you want to replace a value only if something else holds, you can check for this in the `BIND` with the `IF` operator